# Mosfet transconductance in the saturation region

Tags: transistors, mosfet, transconductance

what happens to the transconductance of a MOSFET in the saturation region if the gate-source voltage is less than the threshold voltage? Will the transconductance be negative since the equation is given by

[image]

Comment: *if the gate-source voltage is less than the threshold voltage?* Then the MOSFET is in **weak inversion mode**. Grab a textbook about MOSFETs and look up which formulas describe how the MOSFET works in that region of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this equation is valid only in saturation mode which means:

1. Vgs > Vth
2. Vds > (Vgs-Vth)
   and it is the derivative of the saturation current equation.
   when Vgs < Vth you're no more in saturation mode.
   you can check on the web for (gm vs. Vgs) graph, where you can see that at Vgs<Vth the gm=0.